# Form validation disable submit button until all fields are filled in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, forms

Given:
WPF 4.0 desktop-based application. Basic input form with two `TextBox` fields and submit button.

XAML-code:

```xml
<Label Content="Username" />
<TextBox x:Name="Form_UserName" />

<Label Content="Password" />
<TextBox x:Name="Form_Password" />

<Button x:Name="Submit"
        Click="Form_Submit_Button_Click"
        Content="Submit" />
```

Task:
Implement logic where submit button is enabled if and only if two `TextBox` fields are filled.

The classical way to solve this issue is a use of event handlers such as `onLostFocus()` or something like that, where we can control condition of this fields every time when user switch focus from the field.

But since my project is WPF-based, I prefer to use a native way to work with forms — data binding mechanism. I read some articles from this site and MSDN too about form validation, but in almost all examples is proposed to use MVVM framework and I would like to implement it without any framework.

Also, I tried to play with `IMultiValueConverter` but no worked result is received.

How to solve the problem with the data binding as simple as possible (I'm only starting with WPF)?

Comment: MVVM is not a framework it is a pattern. Patterns should be used where code is made cleaner. There are frameworks out there but all you need is a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a command that implements `ICommand`. However the frameworks just make writing these easier and I would suspect this would still be easier than another solution you might come across

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be easily done using the WPF validation mechanisms. First since you want to follow the WPF architecture I would reccomend you to use the WPF [Command model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms752308%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Now to implement your functionality, you can add a `CommandBinding` to the Window/UserControl or to the `Button` itself:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="Save">

<Button.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Save" 
                    Executed="Save_Executed" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute" />
    </Button.CommandBindings>
</Button>
```

Now you can subscribe to the `CanExecute` event to enable or disable your button based on your validation logic. I recommend these reads before you continue:

[Validation in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx)

[Using Custom Validation Rules in WPF](http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/using-custom-validation-rules-in-wpf.html)

The simplest way to do your requirement is as given below:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="GridScroll.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridScroll"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="User Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=UserName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Password" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Password,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="Save">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="Save" 
                    Executed="Save_Executed" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute"/>
        </Button.CommandBindings>

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class Window1 : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private string userName;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return userName;
        }
        set
        {
            userName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return password;
        }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Your code
    }

    private void Save_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password));

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.